# Modifying a Boss DS-1 Distortion pedal, possible lifted pads

Tags: integrated-circuit, soldering

My apologies if this is in the wrong place, seems like the people on this section would know what to do in this situation. I am brand new to circuit bending and electronics work in general, really starting to realize how much of an art it is to do things right.

The first project I decided to tackle before messing with the board on a Roland TR-505 drum machine I have (I will need to be much better with my soldering) is the Keeley Mod for the Boss DS-1. Well documented so it seems like a good start. ANYWAYS...

I started desoldering (Using a chisel tip, 40 watt iron and a desoldering pump) and was running into constant problems using the pump. I'll be getting a wick soon, but in the process, a few pads have lifted, exposing copper (but it doesn't look like it exposed the board itself). Is there an easy way of fixing this? I've heard scraping away the guard on a little bit of the tracing and soldering to that is a standard fix.

Also, one thing I have heard is to always be careful around the IC chip. I haven't touched it with my iron, just removed a few caps and resistors nearby. I kept touching the IC chip to see if it was getting warm, and at a point it was (but not hot, just a light warmth). How do you guys know if something like that is fried until you are totally done with your modifications?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: If I can make a gentle suggestion, there are a ton of websites available that will teach you how to solder.  Spend a day practicing your soldering skills before you start on your project.  And: do as many projects as you can.  Soldering is one skill that only gets better the more you do it.

Comment: Rule of thumb: if you're able to touch the IC while desoldering, it hasn't been damaged by heat.  Most of the DIP ICs used in pedals like this are remarkably rugged and will withstand a lot of abuse.

Comment: I'll add that 40W of heat is far too much for these little connections. That's a great soldering iron for bigger things, but for these little connections, half that amount of heat would be best. The high heat is probably what is causing the pads to lift.

Answer (score 1):

Try to work on scrap boards and remove all the components clean it and solder back all the components. Watching videos on youtube is extremely helpful and everything looks easy but doing the actual can get quite difficult. as far as the IC check for burned marks and solder shorts on each pins. let me know if you need help fixing the exposed copper and broken traces